# Behavior testing a modal window fill in with capybara, cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, fancybox-2

I am using [fancybox2-rails](https://github.com/kyparn/fancybox2-rails) gem for login modal windows, and capybara's method fill_in(field, :with => value) can't find the field, how to test it? what additional tools can i use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this custom method to fill my fields :

```
def fill_field_by_css(css_path, value)
  page.find(css_path).set value
end
```

If your field ID is `#name` you can fill the input by using `fill_field_by_css('#name', 'your_value')`